# How to update parent's variable in child component after child has called parents function that has http request

Tags: javascript, angular

I cannot seem to see the changed @Input in the child component after it was updated in parents http request.

This is an example:

**Parent**

```
import { ChildComp } from './child.component';

@Component({
    template: <child [counter]="a" [updateCounter]="updateCounter"></child>,
    directives: [ChildComp]
})

export class ParentComponent { 
    public a = 1;
    public CallBack:Function;

    constructor(private _http:Http) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.CallBack = this.updateCounter.bind(this);
    } 

    public updateCounter() {
        this._http.get('/newcounter/').subscribe(
            data => {
                // update counter
                this.a = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
            },
            error => {},
            () => console.log('updated counter')
        );

    }
}
```

**Child**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
        <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="updateCounter()"></button>
        <p>counter: {{ counter }}</p>
    `,
    inputs: ["counter", "updateCounter"]
})

export class ChildComponent { 
    public counter;
    public updateCounter:Function;

    constructor() {}
}
```

So, this works if there is not http request. But once I have the request, the child view will not update the **counter**.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

One hack i have now is to `setTimeout` on child component to update the counter 500ms after the call to `updateCounter`

Answer (score 1):

Amend the `updateCounter` function of your parent component like this:

```
public updateCounter() {
    let that = this;
    this._http.get('/newcounter/').subscribe(
        data => {
            // update counter
            that.a = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
        },
        error => {},
        () => console.log('updated counter')
    );

}
```

Using `this` in the promise does not reference your class anymore. So you need to keep a reference to `this` in another variable and use that one instead.

Comment: that was my first try, but it did not work. Its like one state behind, it shows previous counter after every button click

Comment: You pass the updateCounter method as reference down to your ChildComponent to trigger the update. According to the docs, I'd propose you use the EventEmitter instead of your solution. Find a sample in the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs